# Why member function parameter const mismatch allowed?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc

Why does this compile? Even though the signature is different?

```
class A { void f(const int  a); };
void A::f(int a) {} //compiles fine
```

I've also tried other signature types, and got mixed results:

```
//Doesn't Compile:
class A { void f(const int*  a); };
void A::f(int* a) {}

class B { void f(const int&  a); };
void B::f(int& a) {}

//Compiles:
class C { void f(int* const  a); };
void C::f(int* a) {}

class D { void f(int& const  a); };
void D::f(int& a) {}
```

Why ?
Where in the C++ specs/standard is it written that the const doesn't matter in these cases?

I've checked on both Visual Studio and GCC.

Comment: Top level const is not part of the function type. Hang on, I'll look for a dupe. Edit: Lol,  too slow.

Comment: @StoryTeller Is there an hidden badge for fastest deduplicated question somewhere that you're chasing? Yee that was fast!

Comment: @BaummitAugen - When you want to shoot, shoot. Don't type :P

Comment: @StoryTeller The comment was to deter potentials answerers to prevent some more duplicate answers while I'm searching, but it appears dividing the work like this works nicely, too. =D

Comment: That's not exactly a duplicate. In const int&  the const IS considered as part of the signature. Which kinda contradicts what's written in the other answers

Comment: Yochai, I'm sorry there's no standard quote on the dupe. But the accepted answer is really good so I felt it was worth the closure. If a normative reference is still of import it's at [\[dcl.fct\]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.fct#5). But that answer is better at translating it.

Comment: @YochaiTimmer That's not a top level const. Read the answers more carefully.

Comment: Right i missed that. Thanks